# Reactjs gets values of the only last selected records

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

**Reactjs** gets userid/values of the only last selected records.

Here I have 3 records in the array via reactjs.

```
{ id: 1, name: "Tony", Age: "18" , gender: "male" },
{ id: 2, name: "John", Age: "21" , gender: "female"},
{ id: 3, name: "Luke", Age: "78" , gender: "male"},
```

whenever I select the  three records from checkbox and submit, only one records gets selected and alerted.

That selected record always be the values/userid of the last checked box.

What am trying to do is to ensure that the code selects and submit all the three records if their corresponding
checbox is checked. In the code below I have also tried

**arr.push()** and **arr.concat()** method but cannot get it to work...

Here is the coding so far

```js
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.useridChanged = this.useridChanged.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      rec: [
        { id: 1, name: "Tony", Age: "18", gender: "male" },
        { id: 2, name: "John", Age: "21", gender: "female" },
        { id: 3, name: "Luke", Age: "78", gender: "male" },
      ],
      chrk: '',
    };
  }


  useridChanged(e) {
    this.setState({ chrk: e.target.value });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    //onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { chrk } = this.state;

    //let arr = [];
    //arr.concat(chrk);

    const arr = [];
    arr.push(chrk);
    alert(arr);
    console.log(arr);


    const data = { check: arr };
    console.log(data);

    /*
    send to database by axios
    axios.post('http://localhost/apidb_react/checkbox.php', data)
              .then(res => console.log(res.data));
    */
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h3>Get values of all Selected Records</h3>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <ul>
            {this.state.rec.map((obj, i)=>(
              <li key={i}>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="chrk"
                  value={obj.id}
                  onChange = {this.useridChanged}
                />
                {obj.name} - {obj.Age}  - {obj.gender} 
              </li>))}
            </ul>
            <button className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />,document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your updated code that will work as you want -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>    
<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

this.useridChanged = this.useridChanged.bind(this);
this.onSubmit= this.onSubmit.bind(this);


    this.state = {
       rec: [
        { id: 1, name: "Tony", Age: "18" , gender: "male" },
        { id: 2, name: "John", Age: "21" , gender: "female"},
        { id: 3, name: "Luke", Age: "78" , gender: "male"},
      ],
checkedIds: []

    };

  }


  useridChanged(e) {
    let checkedIds = this.state.checkedIds;
    if(e.target.checked){
      checkedIds.push(e.target.value);
    } else{
      checkedIds = checkedIds.filter((id) => id!== e.target.value )
    }
      this.setState({
        checkedIds
      });
 }

onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 var selectedIds = this.state.checkedIds;
console.log(selectedIds);


const data = { check: selectedIds };
console.log(data);

/*
send to database by axios
axios.post('http://localhost/apidb_react/checkbox.php', data)
          .then(res => console.log(res.data));
*/
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <div>
          <h3>Get values of all Selected Records</h3>



<form onSubmit = {this.onSubmit}>



          <ul>
            {this.state.rec.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>

                 <input type="checkbox" name="chrk" value={obj.id}

                onChange={this.useridChanged}
              />{obj.name} - {obj.Age}  - {obj.gender} 


              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>


 <button className="btn btn-primary">
              Submit
            </button>

        </form>


        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));


</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to send data like this :

```
[
    { id: 1, name: "Tony", Age: "18" , gender: "male", checked: true },
    { id: 2, name: "John", Age: "21" , gender: "female", checked: false},
    { id: 3, name: "Luke", Age: "78" , gender: "male", checked: false},
  ],
```

If so, you need to change your code a bit like below:

```
 class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
   this.state = {
       rec: [
        { id: 1, name: "Tony", Age: "18" , gender: "male" },
        { id: 2, name: "John", Age: "21" , gender: "female"},
        { id: 3, name: "Luke", Age: "78" , gender: "male"},
      ],
      chrk: '',

    };
  }

  useridChanged(name, e) {
     let rec = this.state.rec.map(a => ({...a}));
     rec.map(i => i.checked = i.name === name ? e.target.checked : i.checked ? i.checked : false);
     this.setState({ rec }, () => console.log(this.state.rec));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
            {this.state.rec.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>

                 <input type="checkbox" name="chrk" value={obj.id}

                onChange={this.useridChanged.bind(this, obj.name)}
              />{obj.name} - {obj.Age}  - {obj.gender} 


              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wyotl9)  While Submit you can get this checkbox state directly and pass to servevr

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to send as `data` only ids of checked elements or whole elements.

**If you want to send only id's**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    rec: [
      { id: 1, name: "Tony", Age: "18", gender: "male" },
      { id: 2, name: "John", Age: "21", gender: "female" },
      { id: 3, name: "Luke", Age: "78", gender: "male" }
    ],
    chrk: []
  };

  useridChanged = e =>
    this.setState({ chrk: this.state.chrk.concat(e.target.value) });

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { chrk } = this.state;
    // chrk is your data
     /*
    send to database by axios
    axios.post('http://localhost/apidb_react/checkbox.php', data)
              .then(res => console.log(res.data));
    */
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h3>Get values of all Selected Records</h3>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <ul>
              {this.state.rec.map((obj, i) => (
                <li key={i}>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    name="chrk"
                    value={obj.id}
                    onChange={this.useridChanged}
                  />
                  {obj.name} - {obj.Age} - {obj.gender}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
            <button className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**If you want to send whole elements**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    rec: [
      { id: 1, name: "Tony", Age: "18", gender: "male" },
      { id: 2, name: "John", Age: "21", gender: "female" },
      { id: 3, name: "Luke", Age: "78", gender: "male" }
    ],
    chrk: []
  };

  useridChanged = e =>
    this.setState({ chrk: this.state.chrk.concat(e.target.value) });

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { chrk, rec } = this.state;
    let data = [];
    rec.map(item =>
      chrk.map(check => {
        if (check === item.id.toString()) data.push(item);
      })
    );
    
     /*
    send to database by axios
    axios.post('http://localhost/apidb_react/checkbox.php', data)
              .then(res => console.log(res.data));
    */
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h3>Get values of all Selected Records</h3>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <ul>
              {this.state.rec.map((obj, i) => (
                <li key={i}>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    name="chrk"
                    value={obj.id}
                    onChange={this.useridChanged}
                  />
                  {obj.name} - {obj.Age} - {obj.gender}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
            <button className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```